# "dancing divs" using jquery .innerhtml, .appendto and setInterval

Tags: jquery, html, setinterval, innerhtml, appendto

I'm working on a HTML/JavaScript game that has a Spell Bar (div) with spells that show a count down (also divs). When more than one of the spell divs is added they will be positioned slightly below the container div.

I've attached a jsfiddle link with all the code. I searched almost everywhere on Google, but didn't found any answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9dgu7so/

I also tried using this function instead of `SetInterval`, with no results.

```
function interval(func, wait, times){
    var interv = function(w, t){
        return function(){
            if(typeof t === "undefined" || t-- > 0){
                setTimeout(interv, w);
                try{
                    func.call(null);
                }
                catch(e){
                    t = 0;
                    throw e.toString();
                }
            }
        };
    }(wait, times);

    setTimeout(interv, wait);
};
```

replacing the old one with

```
interval(function(){ HBSpellDown(champName, slot, cd); }, 1000, cd);
```

I tried commenting out most of `danger_spell` and `danger_spell_inner`, but that didn't help either.

Without the `setInterval` part it works, but I need the to show the countdown.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the inner div causing the outer div to be re-positioned. Try putting `position: absolute;` in the style for `danger_spell_inner`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9dgu7so/1/)

Comment: you made my day, really! thank you so much, I was starting to think it was caused by a bug in java itself :-)